# WPF Docking to Top on a VerticalAlign Stretch with MaxHeight

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm seeking a behaviour which combines that of `VerticalAlign="Stretch"` and `VerticalAlign="Top"`. Please observe the following markup:

```
<Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" MaxHeight="200">
    ...
</Border>
```

This acts as I intend it to until the container of Border becomes greater than 200 tall. At this point, Border becomes 200 tall and centers itself in its container.

I cannot wrap it in DockPanel with DockPanel.Dock="Top". I also cannot set its container to VerticalAlign="Top". The reason is that both of these cause Border to no longer expand vertically to fill the containers available space (up to 200).

So, in order to consider this problem solved, the following must occur:

- Border must expand to fill its parent's available space up until its MaxHeight is reached.
- Border's top edge must meet its parent's top edge.
- Border does not need to be a `<Border>`.

Comment: Can you add markup for the container?

Comment: Yes, markup may be added to the container.

Comment: What I meant was can you add an example of the container markup? Or is it just as simple as the grid in an answer below?

Comment: It's really that simple. Truth be told, it's being embedded in to an ultimately complicated window, but everything outside the container <grid> is irrelevant.  Assume that Erno's code sample is the only thing on a <Window /> and go from there. I'm actually testing this on a blank window with Erno's markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

voila:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition MaxHeight="200"  />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Background="Yellow" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: At first I had this too but this solution is not going to size the top row to 200 when possible.

Comment: You are right, I got sidetracked by the, to me hard to understand requirements.

Comment: This seems to solve the problem, but I'm waiting for Kivin to provide some feedback that we've properly understood the problem.

Comment: Elad has it bang on with this solution. Does everything we needed it to.